# Install grails 2.2.0 ubuntu grails-ppa not found

Tags: unix, grails, ubuntu

want to install grails on ubuntu 11.10

f0llowed the instructions on the grails website

http://grails.org/download/ubuntu

i can add repository and update but when i type

```
sudo apt-get install grails-ppa
```

it returns

```
Paketlisten werden gelesen... Fertig
Abhängigkeitsbaum wird aufgebaut       
Status-Informationen einlesen... Fertig
E: Paket grails-ppa kann nicht gefunden werden
```

the last line is german for

```
E: package grails-ppa could not be found.
```

what should i do better?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The maintainer of that ppa has moved on to create http://gvmtool.net/ which is a much more robust solution which also supports Groovy, Griffon, and other technologies. We haven't yet updated the web site to make that more clear, but GVM is definitely the way to go.

Comment: Ah Okay, that was a really easy installation thank you, letsdev!

Comment: Up-voted @Burt's answer. Here's a step-by-step using GVM that worked for me even on 10.04 https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-grails-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-vps